# что такое padding и trailer в ethernet пакете?

Tags: linux, c, сеть, сетевое-программирование

Сделал icmp пакет. Заполнил ему данными в размер 8 байт. Отправляю. wireshark показывает, что в ethernet есть padding и trailer, которые состоят из нулей. Ну я так понял, что padding это выравнивание, но зачем оно нужно? Добавил алфавит английских букв в icmp пакет. padding исчез. Но trailer всё также есть. Хотя пакет занимает больше 64 байт.

Comment: *padding* с английского будет звучать примерно как *дозаполнение*, а *trailer* — *хвостик*. Может быть вам англо-русский словарь?

Comment: Здесь вроде бы, нет ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120492/why-is-there-a-padding-in-ip-packet

Comment: выравнивание это `align`, а `padding` это отступ, он нужен для выравнивания, но сам им не является

Answer (score 2):

*padding* (англ. *набивка*) — это дополнительные (обычно нулевые) быйты в сообщение, которые должны быть. Нужны они, чтобы выровнять определённые поля или размер всего сообщения или его части (заголовка) до определённой длины. Вообще говоря, наличие оных обычно нормальное и часто обязательное явление.

*trailing [bytes]* (вероятно это понимается под *trailer*, от англ. *trail*, *тащить [за собой]*) — это лишние байты в конце сообщения, которых обычно быть не должно.

Что собственно не так с пакетами без кода их создания и содержимого оных понять невозможно.